# Hosts.json in Azure Functions 2.0 doesn't seem to respect queues properties

Tags: azure, azure-functions

My hosts.json file is this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:01:00",
      "batchSize": 2,
      "maxDequeueCount": 2,
      "newBatchThreshold": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Yet I can see that there are at least 50 concurrent sessions running. Is there a known issue with this or should I be doing something different to be able to limit the amount of concurrent functions running from a queue trigger?

If seen WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT but it doesn't appear to be fully supported yet.

Comment: What/how are you identifying the the concurrent sessions count?

Comment: My function makes an insert on a SQL table. I'm querying it and can make that there are about 50 new inserts in seconds...

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN - Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#host-json):

> batchSize
>
> The number of queue messages that the Functions runtime retrieves simultaneously and processes in parallel. When the number being processed gets down to the newBatchThreshold, the runtime gets another batch and starts processing those messages. So the maximum number of concurrent messages being processed per function is batchSize plus newBatchThreshold. This limit applies separately to each queue-triggered function.

So, the number of concurrent operations is limited by this constraint.  In the case of the sample config, that would be at most 3 concurrent operations.  However, if there are more messages queued, then they will be processed after the current batch.  Depending on the speed at which each message is processed, this can be a large number of messages per second.

As you are monitoring the end result this may appear as there are large number of operations in a very small time window, but they are not necessarily concurrent.

Comment: The problem is that I'm getting to the limit of concurrent connections on SQL therefore my mention of concurrent sessions. I'm positive I don't have a leak on the SQL connection and I was assuming the connection would be closed once the function finishes and calls another batch...

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge You need a better monitoring on the process. Maybe create a log file to monitor each connection being opened/closed to ensure that you are tidying up correctly.  My point is that it may not be a concurrent functions issue.